# covering positively disjoint sets with finite balls

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I have a question if $X$ is a separable bounded metric space and $A$,$B\subset X$ are sets such that
$d(A,B)>0.$

Does there exists sets $A^{\prime}$ and $B^{\prime}$ such that each of them is
a finite union of open balls $A^{\prime}\cap B^{\prime}=\emptyset$, $A\subset
A^{\prime},$ and $B\subset B^{\prime}?$

Answer (score 1):

If $X= \mathbb{R}$, $A=]- \infty,-1]$, $B=[1, \infty[$, and $d(x,y)=\frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}$,it is false.
The balls of ($\mathbb{R},d)$ are the same that the balls of $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric. So $A$ can not be covered with a finite union of balls, without covering $B$.

Comment: What does compactness have to do with anything?

Comment: How does your claim about the topology imply anything about balls? Being an open ball is not a topological invariant.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited.

Answer (score 1):

No. $X$ could have very few sets which are finite unions of open balls. For example, let $X$ be an infinite set with the discrete metric. Then the only open balls are singletons and the whole space, so the only sets that are finite unions of open balls are finite sets and the whole space. So if we take $A$ and $B$ to be disjoint and infinite, then your goal is impossible.

Comment: yes thanks. I forgot to add separability of X. But I guess you can have a countable set.